# Inkscape breaks graphic in input

Tags: svg, visio, inkscape

I have a visio drawing where I need to write text inside the boxes.

When I save the visio drawing as a SVG the text which consists of multiple lines is overwritten on top of each other when previewed in Inkscape. Note the purple box.

[image]

Has anybody encountered this before, is there a solution?

**EDIT:** after trying multiple software I noticed that it is not Visio output to blame, but it is Inkscape input. Obviously it breaks the file when when it reads it.

Any solution?

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be about programming. If you think you've found an inkscape bug, raise it in the inkscape bug tracker.

Comment: @RobertLongson should I delete the question from here?

Comment: Probably. I'd try raising it here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape Be sure to include the markup that fails so that Inkscape developers can properly investigate it.